# Is it possible to have a text area sent as a hyperlink and retain it's value?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, collaboration

Trying to have a page with a text area in which you input a value and then have the ability to send that page to someone else with a hyperlink and the text area would still retain the inputed value.  Similar to Google docs share feature.

Looking where to start researching and any relevant resources to build this functionality.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, my apologies for the open ended question.  If someone can provide me a tutorial on how to execute it with simple Javascript/jQuery, that would really be a helpful starting point for me.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at: 
 - Javascript & jQuery (but I guess you are already aware of those). 
 - MySQL for more advanced use, or GET for easy use (PHP) 
 - jQuery .html function 
 - $.ajax function

Comment: Thanks Nathan! I was wondering if you have any specific Javasript/ Jquery tutorials that I should look into.  I am still fairly new to development so I am looking for the right keywords or method to start researching. Thanks again.

Comment: [PHP GET](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm), [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), [jQuery html](http://api.jquery.com/html/). I don't know if there is a specific tutorial on what you want, but you have to try things until you get a basic understanding of the language and you are able to think out solutions yourself.